# How to count the specific item in dynamic list?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, dynamic-list

```
@Published var storedMedicines: [Medicine] = [
    Medicine(Title: "Medicine 1", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664779248), isTaken: false),
    Medicine(Title: "Medicine 1", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664880248), isTaken: false),
    Medicine(Title: "Medicine 1", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664720990), isTaken: false),
    Medicine(Title: "Medicine 1", Description: "Lower blood sugar", date: .init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1664720990), isTaken: false),
]
```

I want to know how can I count the "isTaken" attribute in here. I want to specifically make it said that "2 isTaken true" and 2 isTaken false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two many ways to do this.

Using `filter`.

```
let trueCount = storedMedicines.filter(\.isTaken).count
let falseCount = storedMedicines.count - trueCount
```

Using `reduce`.

```
let trueCount = storedMedicines.reduce(0, { $0 + ($1.isTaken ? 1 : 0) })
let falseCount = storedMedicines.count - trueCount
```

Comment: NVM i got it, I just add "lazy" at the before the "let"
'lazy let trueCount = storedMedicines.filter(\.isTaken).count'

Comment: Anyway, I really appreciate the help and really thankful for you.